# How to resolve PHP on openshift: Failed to execute: 'control restart'?

Tags: php, wordpress, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have a PHP (wordpress) app on OpenShift. It was working very well, so it stopped to work. I tried to restart using the rhc command, but was impossible. The follows error was shown:

```
>rhc app restart php
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for
/var/lib/openshift/53feXX835973XX99XXXXXXX/php
```

I also tried to restart using scp environment: `ctl_all restart`
But again, it not worked and the follow error was showing:

```
An error occurred executing 'gear restart' (exit code: 1) 
Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/o
penshift/53feXX835973XX99XXXXXXX/php
```

I tried to get a backup of my app using `rhc save-snapshot`, but the backup file always is generated empty (0kb).

And If I try to restart using OpenShift WebConsole I receive the follows error:

```
Restarting PHP 5.3 cartridge (Apache+mod_php)
Application directory "php/" selected as DocumentRoot
Starting PHP 5.3 cartridge (Apache+mod_php)
Application directory "php/" selected as DocumentRoot
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/53feXX835973XX99XXXXXXX/php
```

So, what do I do to solve?

Comment: What do your logs on the gear say? https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202328880-How-do-I-troubleshoot-application-issues-using-the-logs-

Comment: @niharvey - It was necessary to delete that application. Log files had not about that problem. Fortunately I had database backup.